# How to count member's entries, limited by channel?

Tags: members, entries, solspace-user, count

I'm trying to find a way to show a simple entry count for the logged in member, which is limited by channel. I would be using this in a conditional to change the action of a link depending on how many entries they've posted to that channel. Something like this:

```
{if member_group == '8' && {MY_ENTRY_COUNT channel="directory"} > 1}{/if}
```

The only plugin I can find is this one: https://github.com/websecret/number_member_entries

But it doesn't work right to limit by channel - looks like its channels parameter is setup to list channel ID's instead of short names, but I don't think channels even have IDs.

If it makes any difference I'm using Solspace User, but that only appears to have a simple entry_count variable that can't be limited by channel.

Anyone know how else to get a count like this that could be used in an advanced conditional?

Comment: Every channel has an id. If you navigate to the channel area in the CP and hover over a channel youll se the id in the link of your browser.

Comment: Never noticed they had an ID. I guess you learn something new every day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Number member entries](https://github.com/websecret/number_member_entries) plugin looks like it should do the trick.

Channels do have a channel_id, but I can't find it in the EE control panel easily. You could count the number of channels down from the top of your Channels list (under Admin > Channel Administration > Channels). You could also use the [Developer Info](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/developer-info) add-on to find the channel_id.

```
{if member_group == '8'}
  {if {exp:number_member_entries:count channels='1'} > 0}
    Yep, there are entries!
  {if:else}
    No entries here.
  {/if}
{/if}
```

Comment: Thanks to Alex and everyone else who pointed out that channels do have ID numbers. I've managed to get it working with code similar to above now that I found the appropriate channel ID.

Answer (score 0):

I check this plugin it's very useful for me , so I edit it to accept channel short name in channels param.

you can download the new version here:

https://github.com/ahmad-saad/number_member_entries

Regard's.

Comment: Thanks Ahmad. I was hoping someone more savvy than me would update that plugin to allow channel names.